# How to get child class of parent id using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to ask, How can I get the class of child element.
For example if I have this kind of code:

```
<a class="w010 h010 p007 b03 d2 f1" id="category_entertainment">
    <div class="it3 ib3 il3 jt05 jb05 jl10 kt04 kb04 kl03">
        //some codes here. . . 
    </div>
</a>
```

Now I have an anchor tag. My scenario is after clicking the tag. I need to get the class of the div and replace it with my new one.

```
$("#category_entertainment").on('click',function(){

    var new_class = "it3 ir3 il3 jt10 jr05 jl05 kt03 kr04 kl04";

    $("#category_entertainment > div).attr("class",new_class); //i tried this but not working.

});
```

Comment: You need to close your quote on the selector: `$("#category_entertainment > div")`

Comment: Ah ok. Syntax error. :) thanks

Comment: The Javascript error console will allow you to see and debug errors like this. Here's how to open it in [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console), [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#opening_the_console), and [Safari](http://gardengnomesoftware.com/wiki/Using_The_Browser_Error_Console#Safari).

Comment: Ok i fixed the syntax but it doesn't change my class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked correctly on my machine:

```
$("#category_entertainment").on('click',function(){

    var new_class = "it3 ir3 il3 jt10 jr05 jl05 kt03 kr04 kl04";

    $("#category_entertainment div").attr("class",new_class);

});
```

My only suggestion would be to make sure this code abode is running after the elements have been created.  If you place this in `window.onload=function() {// assign click handler}` something like that to assure that the element is loaded.  Below is a jsfiddle example.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/stCWS/3/)

Comment: Ok I did that but it affecting my other div tag. :(

Comment: @RochelleCanale which other `div` tag?

Comment: I have another div tag like in my code also. Which is same class name.

Comment: @RochelleCanale do you mean `id` tag? as in `#category_entertainment`?

Comment: I have unique parent ID but the child's class is not unique. Ok I will check it again. If I have wrong enclosing of div. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @RochelleCanale I made an Edit, check it out if you would like.

Comment: Ok I am testing it now.

Comment: Ok it is now changing but the layout is a totally mess. Anyway that's an another problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok i got it working, I fixed the layout. Thanks again. Sorry because I am a beginner in jquery.

Comment: @RochelleCanale Hooray!  Theres no better way to become an expert than by being a beginner ;)